# How to turn generated buttons on and off?

Tags: c#

I'm trying to make a  Wack-A-Mole game in C#. What I've done so far is make a button generate a grid of buttons as the play field. The point of the game will be to click on button that is activated to get a point. Now what I'm stuck on is (as the  title says) making it so that once I click on 'Start' one button will stay active and all the other ones will get disabled.

Here is my code so far :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Whack_a_mole
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            label1.Visible = false;
            label1.Text = "Max size is 5";

        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int Area = Convert.ToInt32(textBox1.Text);
            if (Area < 6)
            {
                GenerateGrid(20, 20, Area, Area, 75, 75);
            } else
            {
                label1.Visible = true;
            }

        }

        private void GenerateGrid(int gridleft, int gridtop, int horizontalCount, int verticalcount, int width, int height)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < verticalcount; i++)
            {
                GenerateRowOfButtons(gridleft, gridtop+height*i, horizontalCount, width, height);
            }
        }

        private void GenerateRowOfButtons (int startX, int startY, int count, int width, int height)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
            {
                GenerateButton(startX+i*width, startY, width, height);
            }
        }

        private void GenerateButton (int x, int y, int width, int height)
        {
            Button button = new Button();
            button.Width = width;
            button.Height = height;
            button.Left = x;
            button.Top = y;
            this.Controls.Add(button);
        }


    }
}
```

Comment: I think you should have a Timer and a loop, the Timer tick runs a loop that iterates all the buttons and decrements a counter associated with each button (make a custom class for a Mole and store it in the button's Tag). When the counter hits 0, the button lights up, becomes enabled and sets another random counter (how long it will stay active for). Each button has the same click handler, the click handler gets the `sender` as the button, casts the Tag to a Mole, increments the whackcounter, disables the button and sets the sleepcounter to another random value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per my comment - please note this code is absolutely untested, might not even compile, because I'm on a cellphone:

```
namespace Whack_a_mole
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private Random _rng = new Random(); //used to determine mole sleep and wake times
        private Timer _t = new Timer(); //ticks ever 0.1 s
        private List<Button> _buttons = new List<Button>(); //track our mole buttons

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            label1.Visible = false;
            label1.Text = "Max size is 5";
            _t.Interval = 100;
            _t.Click += Timer_Tick;
        }

        private void StartButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            _t.Start(); //start the timer

        }

        private void Timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //every 0.1 s we scan the board poke every mole
            foreach(Button b in _buttons){
              b.Enabled = (b.Tag as Mole).IsAwake(); //isawake will sometimes wake a mole up or put it to sleep if we didnt whack it soon enough
              if(b.Enabled) //if the mole is awake
                b.BackColor = Color.Red; //red tbuton = awake mole
              else
                b.BackColor = Color.Gray; //sleeping mole
            }
        }

        private void MoleButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Button b = (sender as Button); //many buttons share this handler; which button was clicked?
            Mole m = (b.Tag as Mole); //get the mole for that button
            m.Whack(); //whack it - puts to sleep and resets the sleep timer
            b.Enabled = false; //turn this button off
            b.BackColor = Color.Gray;
            b.Text = m.WhackCounter.ToString();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int Area = Convert.ToInt32(textBox1.Text);
            if (Area < 6)
            {
                GenerateGrid(20, 20, Area, Area, 75, 75);
            } else
            {
                label1.Visible = true;
            }

        }

        private void GenerateGrid(int gridleft, int gridtop, int horizontalCount, int verticalcount, int width, int height)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < verticalcount; i++)
            {
                GenerateRowOfButtons(gridleft, gridtop+height*i, horizontalCount, width, height);
            }
        }

        private void GenerateRowOfButtons (int startX, int startY, int count, int width, int height)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
            {
                GenerateButton(startX+i*width, startY, width, height);
            }
        }

        private void GenerateButton (int x, int y, int width, int height)
        {
            Button button = new Button();
            button.Width = width;
            button.Height = height;
            button.Left = x;
            button.Top = y;
            button.Tag = new Mole(_rng); //associate a mole with the button
            button.BackColor = Color.Gray;
            button.Enabled = false;
            button.Click += MoleButton_Click; //all mole buttons handled by the smae click handler
            this.Controls.Add(button);
        }


    }
}

  //mole is a thing that has a counter, we decrement every 0.1 seconds by asking IsAwake()
 // the mole may wake up, and it is awake for another random time then sleeps again
  class Mole{

    //count the whacks. will put this on a button text hence public
    public int WhackCounter{get; set;}=0;
    private int _counter = 0; //this tracks how long the mole sleeps / wakes for
    private Random _r;
    private bool _awake = false; //this toggles every time the counter hits 0

    public Mole(Random r){
      _r = r;
      _counter = r.Next(1,100) //init to a random sleep time
    }

    public void Whack(){
      WhackCounter++; //up the whacks
      _counter = r.Next(10,100); //at tenths of a second it sleeps for 1 to 10 seconds
      _awake = false; //put to sleep
    }

    public bool IsAwake(){ //this method decrements the counter then returns if the mole is awake
      _counter--;
      if(_counter < 1){ //did we hit 0? cycle the mole state and re-randomize
        //toggle state
        _awake = !_awake;
        if(_awake)
          _counter = r.Next(20,50); //moles wake for between 2 and 5 seconds
        else
          _counter = r.Next(10,100);
      }
      return _awake;
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [`Enabled` property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.enabled) to decide which `Button`s are on and which `Button`s are off.

IF you only need one `Button` active at a time, a simple way to approach this might be to add a few fields to your `Form1` class.

- A `System.Collections.Generic.List<Button>` to store all the buttons that you create inside of `Form1.GenerateButton`. We can call this `_buttons`, for example.
- A `Button` to store the currently selected button. We can call this `_enabledButton`, for example.
- A `Random` to generate random numbers so you can select a button at random. We can call this `_rng`, for example.

Inside of `GenerateButton`, make sure you set `button.Enabled = false`, then also add `button` to the `_buttons` field.

Then add a method to `Form1`, `ActivateRandomButton` for example, that does something like this...

```csharp
private void ActivateRandomButton()
{
   if (_enabledButton != null)
   {
      // If one of the buttons is already enabled, disable it.
      _enabledButton.Enabled = false;
   }

   // Randomly select a button that you've created and enable it.
   _enabledButton = _buttons[_rng.Next(0, _buttons.Count)];
   _enabledButton.Enabled = true;
}
```

Now after you've generated all your `Button`s, you can call `ActivateRandomButton` to turn one of them "On". You'll probably eventually add a `Timer` and you can call `ActivateRandomButton` in the `Tick` event.

Do be aware that this is a pretty simplistic approach. It has some problems, for example there will always be one and only one button active at a time. It's been a long time since I've played a game of Whack-a-Mole, but I feel like it's possible for there to be multiple moles "active" at a time, or even zero moles "active" at a time. Hopefully though, this answer will give you something to start with and build on.